# How to join multiple random values of different tables in a single query?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 3 tables (called `results`,`users`,`games`), the first one get data from the others, all with a primary auto-increment ID like this:

**results**

```
id      | idusers | idgames
--------+---------+----------
        |         | 
        |         | 
        |         |
```

**users**

```
id      | name    | 
--------+---------+
1       | todd    | 
2       | mario   | 
3       | luigi   |
```

**games**

```
id      | play    | 
--------+---------+
1       | game1   | 
2       | game2   | 
3       | game3   |
```

I wish to randomize users ID and games ID, and join together inside the `results` table like this:

**results**

```
id      | idusers | idgames
--------+---------+----------
1       |  3      |  2
2       |  1      |  1
3       |  2      |  1 (also duplicates are ok)
```

I know for randomize the ID it's supposed to use `SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY NEWID()` and for join together different tables I need to use `INNER JOIN`,

but how to make it all working together in one single query?

Comment: Make use of views instead of table.

Comment: @mic4ael could you explain? instead of "I have 3 tables" should I use views?

Comment: Take a look at this - http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp

Answer (score 0):

One method in MySQL is to use `rand()` and a correlated subquery:

```
select idusers,
       (select id from games order by rand() limit 1) as idgames
from users;
```

If you have a reasonable amount of data (more than a few thousand rows), then there are more efficient methods.

Comment: thanks for reply, I'll check immediately, I have few amount of data

Comment: @Simone . . . Because your sample results use `idgames`.

Comment: argh! my mistake :) ...not `play` but `id`, why not `select id from games` since you need to retrieve data from that table and insert into results?